# Why do I get file not found when I compile Java code?

Tags: java

I'm using Aquamacs, and I have Java Version 8. My OSX version is Mavericks.

This is my code:

```
public class HelloWorld { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      System.out.println("Hello, World");
   }
}
```

and this is how I compile it:

```
Nayans-MacBook-Pro:~ nghosh$ javac HelloWorld.java
javac: file not found: HelloWorld.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

any suggestions?

Comment: goto the directory where the file is placed and invoke it

Comment: Did you navigate in directory with your .java file before executing that command?

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that?

Comment: `cd [path/to/directory]`

Comment: It's because the current working directory (folder) of your terminal is at your home folder, which does not contain the file you want to compile. Here is a link to a tutorial on how to use the Mac terminal: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-mac-os-x-command-line

Answer (score 7):

First navigate to the directory where the `.java` file exist. For example if it is in directory named *java* then navigate to it using *cd java* then
type the command for compile `javac classname.java` then execute using `java classname`